# NamedPipeClientStream StreamReader problem in C++

Tags: .net, visual-c++, named-pipes, streamreader

When reading from a NamedPipes server using the .net **NamedPipeClientStream** class I can only get the data on the first read in C++, every time it's just an empty string. In c# it works every time.

```
pipeClient = gcnew NamedPipeClientStream(".", "Server_OUT", PipeDirection::In);

try
{
    pipeClient->Connect();
}
catch(TimeoutException^ e)
{
    // swallow
}

StreamReader^ sr = gcnew StreamReader(pipeClient);
String^ temp;
while (temp = sr->ReadLine())
{
    // = sr->ReadLine();
    Console::WriteLine("Received from server: {0}", temp);
}
sr->Close();
```

Comment: This problem appears to be related to windows forms and not c++. Running the same code in a console app I do not see the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to C++ null terminator. The NamedPipes Server was sending for example

**"Hello World!\n\0"**

On the first pass this would send

**"Hello World!\n"** leaving **\0** in the pipe. On subsequents sends it would tranmit

**"\0Hello World!\n"**

C# would get the whole string while c++ would terminate the string at the **\0** char.